# curve_fit not optimizing one of the parameters

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I need to fit with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` some data that look like the points in the figure. I use a function `y(x)` (see def below) which gives a constant `y(x)=c` for `x<x0`, otherwise a polynomial (eg a second tilted line `y1 = mx+q`).

I give a reasonable initial guess for the parameters `(x0, c, m, q)`, as show in the figure. The result from the fit shows that all the parameters are optimized except for the first one `x0`.

Why so? 
Is it how I define the function `testfit(x, *p)`, where `x0` (=`p[0]`) appears within another function?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# generate some data:
x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y1 = np.repeat(0, 500)
y2 = x[500:] - 50
y = np.concatenate((y1,y2))
y = y + np.random.randn(len(y))


def testfit(x, *p):
    ''' piecewise function used to fit 
        it's a constant (=p[1]) for x < p[0]
        or a polynomial for x > p[0]     
    '''
    x = x.astype(float)
    y = np.piecewise(x, [x < p[0], x >= p[0]], [p[1], lambda x: np.poly1d(p[2:])(x)])
    return y

# initial guess, one horizontal and one tilted line:
p0_guess = (30, 5, 0.3, -10)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(testfit, x, y, p0=p0_guess)

print('params guessed  : '+str(p0_guess))
print('params from fit : '+str(popt))

plt.plot(x,y, '.')
plt.plot(x, testfit(x, *p0_guess), label='initial guess')
plt.plot(x, testfit(x, *popt), label='final fit')
plt.legend()
```

Output

```
params guessed  : (30, 5, 0.3, -10) 
params from fit : [ 30. 0.04970411   0.80106256 -34.17194401] 

OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated category=OptimizeWarning)
```

Comment: I believe the problem you are facing is similar in nature to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46624376/3005167). You have two options: **1.** use a different fitting algorithm. **2.** try to avoid the vertical edge in your curve by **a** giving it a small slope, or **b** let the polynomial smoothly connect with the constant value).

Comment: As @kazemakase suggests, `curve_fit` will not handle a discrete variable like your p[0] well, as it cannot create a partial derivative for that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by kazemakase, I solved the problem with a smooth transition between the two functions I use to fit (one horizontal line followed by a polynomial). The trick was to multiply one function by `sigmoid(x)` and the other by `1-sigmoid(x)`, (where `sigmoid(x)` is defined below).

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y1 = np.repeat(0, 500)
y2 = x[500:] - 50
y = np.concatenate((y1,y2))
y = y + np.random.randn(len(y))

def testfit(x, *p):
    ''' function to fit the indentation curve 
    p = [x0,c, poly1d_coeffs ]'''
    x = x.astype(float)
    y = p[1]*(1-sigmoid(x-p[0],k=1)) + np.poly1d(p[2:])(x) * sigmoid(x-p[0],k=1)
    return y

def sigmoid(x, k=1):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-k*x))

p0_guess = (30, 5, 0.3, -10 )
popt, pcov = curve_fit(testfit, x, y, p0=p0_guess)
print('params guessed  : '+str(p0_guess))
print('params from fit : '+str(popt))


plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x,y, 'y.')
plt.plot(x, testfit(x, *p0_guess), label='initial guess')
plt.plot(x, testfit(x, *popt), 'k', label='final fit')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I ended up using np.gradient and a convolution to smooth the curve, then plotting it. Something like:

```
def mov_avg(n, data):
    return np.convolve(data, np.ones((n,))/n, mode='valid')
```

If you want a more direct approach, you can try this:

```
def find_change(data):
    def test_flag(pos):
        grad = np.gradient(data) - np.gradient(data).mean()
        return (grad[:pos]<0).sum() + (grad[pos:]>0).sum()
    return np.vectorize(test_flag)(np.arange(len(data)-1)).argmax()

def find_gradient(pos, data):
    return np.gradient(data[:pos]).mean(), np.gradient(data[pos:]).mean()

pos=find_change(x2)
print(pos, find_gradient(pos, data))
```

The first function calculates the point at which the gradient change by comparing the point gradient against the mean gradient, and finds the point from which the gradients are "mostly positive".

Hope it helps